# How does the __self__ attribute of method become a class rather a instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, attributes

The documentation of instance methods confused me, it classifies  methods into two types:the one is retrieved by an instance of a class, the other is created by retrieving a method from a class or instance.

According to the description,

> When an instance method object is created by retrieving a class method object from a class or instance, its `__self__` attribute is the class itself, and its `__func__` attribute is the function object underlying the class method.

the  `__self__` attribute of the more complex methods is a class.
Can someone show me a example to illustrate the situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement may have sounded ambiguous when you read it like that. I'll try to break it down.

> When an instance method object is created by retrieving a class method
>   object from a class or instance...

```
class TestClass(object):
    @classmethod
    def test_method(cls):
        return 1
```

> its `__self__` attribute is the class itself, and its `__func__` attribute
>   is the function object underlying the class method.

So if we have a `obj = TestClass()` then

```
obj.test_method.__self__ == TestClass.test_method.__self__
```

and

```
obj.test_method.__func__ == TestClass.test_method.__func__
```

This statement is specifically about instance methods created from class's class methods.

I hope it is clearer. I have created a snippet [here](https://repl.it/Euk2/2) for you to play around with.

Comment: So a class method retrieved  by an instance or a class is another kind of instance methods, am i right?

Comment: @wowyoo The way I would put it is: "a class method retrieved via an instance or the class itself is the same method".

Comment: Okay, i got it.